# UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication does not exist in ASP.NET 5 RC1-Final

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core

Earlier we used

```
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],
                Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],

            });
```

to authenticate with Azure. Problem is that today we did an upgrade to **ASP.NET 5 RC1-FINAL** and now this method does not exist anymore.

I have searched the net for other solutions, but the ones I have found is using some 3rd part identity service or .UseOAuthBearerAuthentication which is not available in RC1-Final.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This extension method - specific to AAD - has not been ported to vNext. Instead, you're encouraged to directly use the JWT bearer middleware:

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options => {
    options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
    options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
    options.Authority = "https://login.windows.net/tratcheroutlook.onmicrosoft.com";
    options.Audience = "63a87a83-64b9-4ac1-b2c5-092126f8474f";
});
```

Comment: Any chance we'll see a fully realized sample of using the JWT bearer middleware and AAD?

Comment: You can take a look at this new sample, that uses a JS client app with AAD: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/dev/samples/JwtBearerSample